# Add legend for stroke points ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, legend, stroke

I want to add a legend for the thickness of stroke in the graph. 
Do you have any idea how can i do that ?
I can add a legend for the size but i can not for the stroke.

```
sizes <- expand.grid(size = (0:3) * 2, stroke = (0:3) * 2)
ggplot(sizes, aes(size, stroke, size = size, stroke = stroke)) +
  geom_abline(slope = -1, intercept = 6, colour = "white", size = 6) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "red") + 
  scale_size(range=c(2,12), breaks=c(0,01,02),
             labels=c(">=0",">=0.1",">=0.2"), guide="legend")
```

[image: ggplot output]

Comment: Please provide your data (output of `dput(data)`) and your full code for the plot!

Comment: data is fine, but we definitely need the full plot code ...

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to give you the full code. ``` ggplot(sizes, aes(size, stroke, size = size, stroke = stroke)) + 
    geom_abline(slope = -1, intercept = 6, colour = "white", size = 6) + 
    geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "red") + scale_size(range=c(2,12),breaks=c(0,1,2),labels=c(">=0",">=1",">=2"),guide="legend") ```

Comment: HermiPara, can you please confirm the code I copied from your comment into your question? (code in comments is okay, large code is not, more-so when not formatted as code ... plus since comments can be skipped and/or hidden, it's often best to keep the question whole.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that there is a scale function that works out of the box for strokes, but you could ofcourse build your own.

```
sizes <- expand.grid(size = (0:3) * 2, stroke = (0:3) * 2)
ggplot(sizes, aes(size, stroke, size = size, stroke = stroke)) +
  geom_abline(slope = -1, intercept = 6, colour = "white", size = 6) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "red") + 
  scale_size(range=c(2,12), breaks=c(0,01,02),
             labels=c(">=0",">=0.1",">=0.2"), guide="legend") +
  continuous_scale("stroke", "stroke", 
                   palette = function(x){scales::rescale(x, c(0, 6))},
                   breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6))
```

[image]

EDIT:

I just found out about `scales::rescale_pal`, which is probably more elegant that making an ad hoc anonymous function for the continuous scale.

```
continuous_scale("stroke", "stroke", 
                 palette = scales::rescale_pal(c(0, 6)),
                 breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6))
```

Comment: that's exactly what i needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

@teunbrand's answer is for sure the more elegant way.
However, when looking again on your question a had just came up with another workaround that uses an additional layer to create another guide and then manually adjusts this guide to resample the stroke width.
Note that you can use `theme(legend.key.size=unit(2, 'lines'))` to make the legend fit with your stroke size.

```
sizes <- expand.grid(size = (0:3) * 2, stroke = (0:3) * 2)
ggplot(aes(x=size, y=stroke, size = size, stroke = stroke, color=factor(stroke)), data=sizes) + 
  geom_abline(slope = -1, intercept = 6, colour = "white", size = 6) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "red") + # to create one layer that builds a legend for 'color'
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "red", color='black') + 
  theme(legend.key.size=unit(2, 'lines')) +
  scale_size(range=c(2,12),breaks=c(0,1,2),labels=c(">=0",">=1",">=2"),guide='legend') +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes = list(stroke=c(0, 2, 4, 6), color='black'), title='stroke')) # fix the color guide to show stroke width
```

[image]

---